# Access "Business Street" property from Outlook Contacts

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-2007

I am exporting Outlook contacts to .csv file and putting all the Outlook contacts into `List<Outlook.ContactItem> contactItems` I've created a method called ConvertToCSV() to extract each property of particular contact. In this method, we add each contact's properties to List as shown below code:

```
 private void ConvertToCSV(List<Outlook.ContactItem> contactItems)
    {      
        using (var file = File.CreateText(@"D:\ExportContacts1.CSV"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(ContactItemsListToCSV());
            foreach (var arr in contactItems)
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                list.Add(arr.Title);
                list.Add(arr.FirstName);
                list.Add(arr.MiddleName);
                list.Add(arr.LastName);
                list.Add(arr.BusinessAddress);
                list.Add(arr.BusinessAddressStreet);                   
                list.Add(arr.BusinessAddressCity);
                list.Add(arr.BusinessAddressState);
                list.Add(arr.BusinessAddressPostalCode);
                list.Add(arr.BusinessAddressCountry);
                //and other properties of Outlook ContactItem 
              file.WriteLine(list[0] + "," + list[1] + "," + list[2] + "," + list[3]);
              //adding other list items too        
  }
```

When I see the .csv file created by Outlook, I see three properties: `Business street, Business Street 2, Business Street 3`. Which one should I bind to in the above code? In Outlook contacts, I would see tree structure as:

```
      Business Address
          Business Street
          Business Street 2
          Business Street 3
          ...and so on
```

[image]

How can I access these properties from Outlook such that I can get the same .csv file as the Outlook generates? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried picking one of them and seeing how it differs from the other two?  Seeing as there's only three of them you might be able to figure this out via trial and error.

Comment: thanks for the reply but there is no option like Business Street, Business street 2.It has BusinessAddress which gives full address.If i use BusinessAddressStreet gives only street content..so how can i do trail and error here